# Cannot move/resize ubuntu partition to unallocated space

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-10, multi-boot, gparted

I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04 dual booting from a partitioned SSD. I decided I need a little more room for Ubuntu. In GParted, the 12.50GB which I shrunk from Windows (in Windows) shows as unallocated.

When I right-click on my Ext4 Ubuntu partition (`/dev/sdb5`) and select Resize/Move, the slider does not allow me to increase the size (to take over the unallocated space).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to run GParted in [Live CD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install) with Ubuntu to be able to unmount and then resize the partition.

Answer (score 0):

Your ubuntu partition (/dev/sdb5) is mounted(obviously! :p) under root directory. To resize this partition you must have to unmount it. But as your current OS you just can't do it.

So, if you can unmount this partition using a live CD (I haven't tried this), that's cool, you are good to go. Else you have to boot from another ubuntu system, resize your partition and then reboot into the main ubuntu.